# Google Openid authentication and identification of Domain Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, google-openid

I have implemented Google openid authentication for my web application (ruby on rails) , now once authenticated how am i suppose to get the status of that particular user ? like if the user which has been authenticated is a domain admin or not ? i have googled it a bit and came up with Google provisioning ApI and ClientLogin authentication process.... but in case of Clientlogin authentication one has to provide username@domain.com plus the password in the function...

In all i want to know, is their a way to know that a person authenticated by Openid is a domain owner or not ??

Answer (score 0):

According to the open-id specs these are the attributes you can retrieve from your open-id provider (Ex: Google).
http://www.axschema.org/types/